# What is a good directory to export files in windows

Tags: windows, directory, export

I want to put a default directory in my program to export files. But what is a safe directory in windows that is **always** accessible (in all window versions and user modes)?

Comment: There is no such directory, helping users to overwrite each others files is not a built-in feature.  Just create the directory yourself.

Answer (score 0):

the downloads folder? Or a subfolder inside of the downloads folder?